# Sql - To get the max value from result set in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to get the max values for products from result set but i am getting only one row of value. I want to display max value for each product from the result set.

Please find the result set :

```
|Col1     |col2        |col3|    col4 |sum_cnt|
+---------+------------+---------+----------+-------+
|     1003|     2018/03| PC |    Prod1| 105984| 
|     1003|     2018/03| PC |    Prod2|      3| 
|     1003|     2018/03| PC |    Prod3|    695| 
|     1003|     2018/03| PC |    Prod4|   8489| 
|     1003|     2018/02| PC |    Prod1| 101894| 
|     1003|     2018/02| PC |    Prod4|   7758| 
|     1003|     2018/02| PC |    Prod3|    780| 
|     1003|     2018/02| PC |    Prod2|      1| 
|     1003|     2018/01| PC |    Prod4|   7665| 
|     1003|     2018/01| PC |    Prod3|    708| 
|     1003|     2018/01| PC |    Prod2|      5| 
|     1003|     2018/01| PC |    Prod1| 104557| 
|     1003|     2017/12| PC |    Prod2|      2| 
|     1003|     2017/12| PC |    Prod1| 106896| 
|     1003|     2017/12| PC |    Prod3|    857| 
|     1003|     2017/12| PC |    Prod4|   8177| 
|     1003|     2017/11| PC |    Prod2|      1| 
|     1003|     2017/11| PC |    Prod1| 102664| 
|     1003|     2017/11| PC |    Prod3|    724| 
|     1003|     2017/11| PC |    Prod4|   7661| 
+---------+------------+---------+----------+-------+
```

I want to display the Max sum_cnt for each prod for latest date.

I want my output as :

```
|Col1     |col2        |col3|    col4 |sum_cnt|
+---------+------------+---------+----------+-------+
|     1003|     2018/03| PC |    Prod1| 106896| 
|     1003|     2018/03| PC |    Prod2|      5| 
|     1003|     2018/03| PC |    Prod3|    857| 
|     1003|     2018/03| PC |    Prod4|   8489|
```

I have tried below query to fetch the data but i am getting only one record.

Here is the code:

```
select * from tab2 a where sum_cnt = (select max(sum_cnt)  from tab2 b where a.col1= b.col1)
```

Please help me how to achieve this.

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: In desired output, your *sum_cnt* misaligns value with date. For example, record with `106896` has col2 as `2017/12`, not `2018/03`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try using `ROW_NUMBER` here:

```
SELECT Col1, col2, col3, col4, sum_cnt
FROM
(
    SELECT t.*,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY col1, col4 ORDER BY col2 DESC, sum_cnt DESC) rn
    FROM yourTable t
) t
WHERE rn = 1;
```

The logic here is to partition by product, and then order by first date descending, to get the most recent date, and then by count descending, to get the highest count for that most recent date.

Comment: @ Tim, Thank you very much for your help. When i tried the above query for all prods i am not getting max values. Did i missed anything? Kindly let me know.

Comment: What is the significance of `col1`?  Do you want results for each `col1` value?

Comment: Hi tim, col1 is referes to Clientid. Yes,Tim. That is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Consider joining on an an aggregate subquery:

```
select t.col1, t.col2, t.col3, t.col4, agg.max_cnt
from tab2 t
inner join
    (
      select sub_t.col1, sub_t.col4, max(sub_t.col2) AS max_date, 
                                     max(sub_t.sum_cnt) as max_cnt
      from tab2 sub_t
      group by sub_t.col1, sub_t.col4
    ) agg
on t.col1 = agg.col1 and t.col4 = agg.col4 and t.col2 = agg.max_date
order by t.col4
```

Or using CTE:

```
WITH agg AS 
    (
      select sub_t.col1, sub_t.col4, max(sub_t.col2) AS max_date,  
                                     max(sub_t.sum_cnt) as max_cnt
      from tab2 sub_t
      group by sub_t.col1, sub_t.col4    
    )

select t.col1, t.col2, t.col3, t.col4, agg.max_cnt 
from tab2 t
inner join agg
on t.col1 = agg.col1 and t.col4 = agg.col4 and t.col2 = agg.max_date
order by t.col4
```

[Rextester Demo](https://rextester.com/HBFUF30991)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.